# How to catch save row event of inline editing kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using inline editing of kendo ui. but my client requirement is save and edit grid row on focus lost. Can you please tell me is it possible or not. If yes then how to implement it by using php or javascript or jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To implement you must add event listeners through jquery like:

```
$("body").on("blur", "table tr.k-grid-edit-row input", function() {
    //perform the save action
});
```

*Note:* The selector `table tr.k-grid-edit-row input` in the `.on()` is an example. You may have to modify.

The save action will require some Javascript. See [Kendo Grid documentation here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-saveChanges) related to `saveChanges()` and `saveRow()` on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion... One more query Can I fetch new added record or updated record from the grid for save.

Comment: If you test with `saveChanges`, it may do what you want. There is also a `refresh` method in the documentation that can be used to reload the grid after the save if needed.